# Help why counting but not conditional probability only gets the correct answer.

Tags: probability

Let me setup my question with two very simple examples.

Example 1.

A group of 5 students, made up of 2 females and 3 males, are sat at random in a row. What is the probability the first two seats are occupied by females?

Solution by counting:

2* 3!/5!= 1/10

Solution via conditional probability:

2/5 * 1/4 = 1/10.

They agree.

Now let’s try the another problem:

Example 2.

Letters a,b,c,d,e,f are to be place in 3 distinct groups of two.  The assignments are made at random. What is the probability a,b are both in group 1.

Solution via counting:

4c2 / (6c2 *4c2)= 1/6c2= 1/15

Can’t be solved via conditional probabilities as follows:

P(a in group 1) p( b in group 1| a in group 1) =? 1/3 *1/3

Not the same answer.

Question:

Why does conditional probability work in example one and not( as how I have applied it) not work in problem 2.

I gather it’s how random is being a implied.

in example 2, random means assume all permutations are equally likely. Sometimes, but not all the time, that exact language is written.  So, if I apply conditional probability, as I have attempted, it fails because that would require each letter have equal probability for assignment and that is assuming too much.

Now, assume the same language, all permutations are equally likely, to example 1. Why does conditional probably, as I applied now work, because it seems It still assumes singleton assignments are equally likely, which is not assumed?

Comment: $P(a~\text{in group}~1)$ is indeed $\frac{1}{3}$ however $P(b~\text{in group}~1\mid a~\text{in group}~1)$ is not $\frac{1}{3}$.  Given that $a$ is in group $1$, treating the seats within the groups as distinct there are $5$ equally likely seats available, only one of which is in group $1$, it should have been $\frac{1}{5}$ here, not $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: P( $b$ in group 1| $a$ in group 1) = 1/5. 5 places are left for $b$

Comment: Do not make the mistake of thinking that probability is always the number of good outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes.  Yes, there are three discernable outcomes if we don't keep track of which seat in the groups are which.  No, they are not equally likely.  You have two outcomes when playing the lottery, you win or you lose.  You don't win with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ however.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional probability in the second case is wrong. $a$ indeed has probability $\frac 13$ to end up in the first group, but with one of the two slots filled, the three groups are not equally probable for $b$, with only one of the five remaining available slots in the first group.